# Failed to Start X-Server Linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, x-server

When i am booting system using USB it's give me this error some how now i was able to install Linux mint mate version but i want Linux mint cinnamon. Even though still  getting same error when starting. i have tried this commands but they are not helping

- VGA : AMD  Radeon 2GB
- I5 processor
- 4 GB RAM
  -dell vostro 3000 i5

**DISPLAY AND VGA DETAILS**

```
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5916] (rev 02)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0794]
--
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230] [1002:666f] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

**Other**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Release:    18.1
Codename:   serena
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the *graphical setup* instead of *boot live cd* (or something like that) option when the USB boots up. If that doesn't work (or the option doesn't exist) then select the *boot live cd* entry, press *E* on your keyboard and go to the almost last line and replace *quiet splash* with *nomodeset*. If there is no *quiet splash* just place it after the *ro*. Press F10 now and boot up should work now.

Comment: thank you very much for replying ill try your method and update my result soon